# How to get title attribute of element and insert it after element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, jquery-append

I have a list with list elements like this...

```
<li class="first leaf">
  <a href="/admin/store/orders/view" title="View and process the orders.">View orders</a>
</li>
```

And I want to take the title attribute and append it as a div after the `<a>` like this...

```
<li class="first leaf">
  <a href="/admin/store/orders/view" title="View and process the orders.">View orders</a>
  <div>View and process the orders.</div>
</li>
```

So far, I am here...

```
(function ($) {    
  $('#block-menu-menu-admin-welcome li a').each(function () {
    $(this).append('<div>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</div>');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

But it isn't working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you want `.after()` instead of `.append()`? `.after()` [works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/o3qohz4n/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) insert html to selected element but you need to insert html after selected element. Use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead.

```
$('#block-menu-menu-admin-welcome li a').each(function () {
    $(this).after('<div>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</div>');
});
```

```js
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).after('<div>' + this.title + '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="first leaf">
    <a href="/admin/store/orders/view" title="View and process the orders.">View orders</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but cant get this to work still. I printed a message with console.log ( 'test' ); and it showed in console, so i know jquery and the js file are being noticed.

Comment: @Collins The code work in snippet. So your code has problem. Check console for error.

Comment: No errors in console. Thank you for your help, I can see it works, I'll have to debug on my end

Answer (score 2):

Your first this in your loop is a reference to the anchor. You have to comb out of that to its parent element and append to that.

```
$(this).parent().append('<div>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/ztgb6cs4/3/) for you.

```
$(function(){

     $('.first').append($('.first a').attr('title'));

});
```